# How can I Implement KeyListeners/ActionListeners into the JFrame?

Tags: java, game-mechanics

I'll get to the point:  I have a player in my game that you control with the keyboard yet the key methods in the player class and ActionListener w/ KeyAdapter in the Board class don't seem to fire.

So far I've tried adding these key methods into the JFrame, doesn't seem to let me move him even though other objects that I have (enemies) can move fine.

Here's part of the JFrame class with the event listeners:

```
    frm.addKeyListener(KeyBoardListener);

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
        nSound.play();
        StartB.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        cards.remove(StartB);
        frm.remove(TitleL);
        frm.remove(cards);
        frm.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        frm.add(nBoard); //Add Game "Tiles" Or Content. x = 1200
        nBoard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 420));
        cards.revalidate();
        frm.validate();
}

    public KeyListener KeyBoardListener = new KeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent args0) 
    {
    int key = args0.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        nBoard.S.vx = -4;

    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        nBoard.S.vx = 4;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        nBoard.S.vy = -4;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        nBoard.S.vy = 4;    
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        nBoard.S.fire();
    }

    }   

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent args0) 
    {
    int key = args0.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        nBoard.S.vx = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {   
        nBoard.S.vx = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        nBoard.S.vy = 0;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        nBoard.S.vy = 0;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent args0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    };
```

Comment: Using the debugger would probably help you alot. Are you familiar with how to use it?

Comment: please name variables with the first letter in lowercase, as Java standards

Comment: Could you perhaps point me in the right direction to a debugging tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your JFrame doesn't have keyboard focus. Try this:

> frm.requestFocus()

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135223/obtaining-focus-on-a-jpanel) may be useful as well.

Comment: I can't tell you how happy I am!  I requested focus on the specific Board component (like the Stacks Exchange question suggested) and it worked!